# jQuery variable reference order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question, in the code below if I declare the start_date & end_date variables before $.each the last part which inserts some span tags doesn't work, but if they are declared after $.each then it does.

Why is this? I cannot figure it out and I have no ideas at all.

```
var dates_para = $("#field_dates p");

dates_para.each(function(){
    var html_content = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(html_content.replace("–", ""));
});

var start_date =  $("#start_date");
var end_date = $("#end_date");

start_date.after("<span id='start_datepicker' class='datepicker'></span>");
end_date.after("<span id='end_datepicker' class='datepicker'></span>");
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Can you demonstrate this, perhaps in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Is it possible that your ids don't exist until after you remove the hyphens?  For example, `<div id='start-_date'>...</div>`?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @ScottSauyet, I think `#start_date` and `#end_date` are created by this line `$(this).html(html_content.replace("–", ""));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `#start_date` and `#end_date` elements are parts of the paragraphs, then writing new html to the paragraphs will create new elements and the old references are invalidated.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.

Now you've said it, it all seems so obvious!

Thanks again.